# Can I mark an immutable borrow as exclusive in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a data structure, that is somewhat like a RwLock. It is not re-entrant, but the actual locking mechanism is a const function. Is there any way that I can mark this function as "exclusive_borrow" without switching it to be be a mutable function. That way multiple calls to 'read' will be caught at compile time instead of panicking.

```
struct MyRwLock<T> {
  t: T,
}

impl MyRwLock {
  // Works fine, but doesn't enforce on compile time that there is 
  // only 1 Guard.
  pub fn read(&self) -> ReadGuard<'_, T> { ... }

  // Enforces only 1 ReadGuard at compile time, but unnecessarily 
  // requires MyMutex to be mutable to read.
  pub fn mut_read(&mut self) -> ReadGuard<'_, T> { ... }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting way to look at it and makes sense locally.

From a composability perspective I fear this may be harmful though. Now if the user previously had a const function which calls to self.myrwlock.read(), that function must be marked "&mut self", further forcing the caller to mark the struct as mut. 

Now that I write this though, I guess that's the point. That to guarantee an exclusive borrow it has to be guaranteed all the way up...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&mut` is a bit of a misnomer. It actually means *exclusive* reference, not mutable. If that's what you want, then it's correct to use `&mut`.

In fact, there was a [proposal to rename `&mut`](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/05/13/focusing-on-ownership/) back in 2014. It never came through, but you might occasionally hear whispers of the ["mutpocalypse"](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=27023516) today.